# Set checkbox value based on value from Map attribute in Lightning Component markup

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have map attribute in lightning component. It has id key and value is true or false for checkbox.

```
<aura:attribute name="customMap" type="Map" />
```

I want to iterate via array and get value from this map (that is already populated).

```
<aura:iteration items="{! v.customList }" var="customListItem">
   <lightning:input aura:id="{! customListItem.Id }" type="checkbox" label=" " onchange="{! c.checkCustomMap }" checked="SET_CHECKED_OR_ONCHECKED"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can workaround with two more steps:

The Component:

```
<aura:attribute name="mapObj" type="String[]" />
    <aura:iteration items="{! v.customList }" var="customListItem">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.mapObj}" var="mapObjItem">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!mapObjItem.key == customListItem.id}">
                <lightning:input aura:id="{! customListItem.Id }" type="checkbox" label=" " checked="{!mapObjItem.value}"/>
            </aura:if>
        </aura:iteration>
   </aura:iteration>
```

Matching the Map key with the custom list usong `aura:if`. If key matched then print the checkbox with the value that Map contains. It can be `false` or `true`. It will show checkbox for the keys present in Map only.

The controller:-

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        // .... logic to set list
        component.set('v.customList', arr);


        // .... setting up the map
        component.set('v.customMap', myMap);

        var mapObj = [];
        for (var prop of myMap.keys()) {
          var mapItem = {};
          mapItem.key = prop;

          // if value is boolean type
          mapItem.value = myMap.get(prop);
          // if value is String. Don't use above statement if this is true.
          mapItem.value = myMap.get(prop) == 'true' ? true : false;
          mapObj.push(mapItem);
        }
        component.set('v.mapObj', mapObj);

    },

    checkCustomMap : function(component, event, helper) {

      // To do
    }
})
```

Here I converted the `Map` into object list accessible in the component.

**Note: If Map has checkbox value as String, it will check all checkbox regardless of value (true/false). So, it required to be converted in Boolean type for correct re-rendering.**

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to build yourself a simple array of true/false values that matches the `Map`.

In your controller you could build yourself both a keys and values array and use one to work out the other.

```
var keys = Object.keys(yourMap);
var keyObjects = [];

keys.forEach(function(key){
  var keyObject = {};
  keyObject.key = key;
  keyObject.selected = yourMap[key].selected;
});

component.set('v.keyObjects',keyObjects);
```

Then use the `name` attribute to store some data as I don't think pass through values are allowed. If you don't want to do that, use a standard input, it's pretty easy to style them the way you want. You can't use `aura:id` either, as it gets rewritten.

```
<aura:iteration items="{! v.keyObjects }" var="obj">
  <lightning:input name="{! obj.key }" type="checkbox" label=" " onchange="{! c.checkCustomMap }" checked="{!obj.selected}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

Finally in the `checkCustomMap` function, you would use the `event.getSource()` method to get the key via the `name` attribute.

Comment: Do you think that I need additional iteration for each checkbox? For example I can have about 20 records and for each of this record I need to set checkbox.

Comment: Well, this technique is trying to avoid the iteration that Ashwani's technique uses - you only need one here, with the caveat that you need an extra loop to set it up in the controller. To clarify - you only need one `aura:iteration` for the whole list.

Comment: The thing is that my list has wrapper class type actually. In my case I need values from the wrapper class in other internal components. And one of variable in wrapper is custom object. Id of this custom object is what I need for my custom checkbox. In this case I think I need to try Ashwani's solution. What do you think?

Comment: You can still expose your `Map` and use wherever you like - the `Array` is just a way to iterate the map as discrete objects

Comment: You can even set it up so that you have both a plain `Array` and a `Map` pointing to the same wrapper object. The `Array` is used for any iteration, the `Map` is used for easy object access.